# Garbage Collection Impact of independent arraylist building vs Comparator logic

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, garbage-collection

Question to the gurus in Java Garbage Collection. Wanted to understand if/any performance impact to the Heap Memory when we do sorting via the following techniques

Collection of objects with a unique member variable

```
ArrayList<Car> 

Class Car{
boolean preferredVehicle;
}
```

Now we need to sort and show the preferredVehicles to the top of a selection list

**Method 1:**

1. Create two Lists one regularList and one PreferredList
2. Iterate the CarList and then add to PreferredList if boolean is true
3. Add the non Preferred Car to the non PreferrdList
4. Add All non preferred to the complete Preferred List once Car List loop completes

**Method 2 :**
Collections.sort with a Comparator

Is there a quantifiable difference in performance and which one is more friendly in future garbage collection and heap memory consumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 lists will definitely acquire more space and imagine the list being huge.And, if you won't preallocate the desired list capacity, adding an element can result into another list object allocation of double the size and thus more work for gc. 
Apply sorting on the same list if you don't care the original order.

Comment: thats a good perspective "if you dont care for the original order"

Comment: @satts I guess, it's all the other way round: 1. Sorting is `O(n * log(n))`, so it's slower for huge lists. 2. It also needs some temporary memory (AFAIK there's no stable sort using no temporary memory), so it might be as costly as the two lists. 3. It's stable, which means that you can preserve the original order.

Comment: @maartinus I agree with you that the sorting is O(nlog(n)). In this case, sorting is based on Boolean which means that if you arrange trues in the beginning and false at the other end, you can sort the original list in O(n) without extra space

Answer (score 0):

Method #1 is `O(n)`, whereas method #2 is `O(n * log n)`. So I would go with #1.
As for GC, I don't see a real difference, mainly because the `Car` instances are the same.
HTH,
Yinon

Comment: Even though Car instances will be same but list container is not. And, if list capacity is not predefined on instantiation, many list object's allocations will happen on insufficient capacity

Comment: Also, on the same list, you can achieve O(n)